# Mathematical proof that there is no infitely recursive selector in CSS?

Tags: css, proof

Some have claimed that there exists no CSS selector that can crash a browser by entering an infinite loop as it tries to find all matching elements in the document ree. Can this be proved mathematically? If so, how?

Comment: "Some"? The the tree has, by definition, no cycles, so iterating through it to find matches can't lead to an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1):

That's very simple to prove. The browser never tries to find a matching element for a selector.

The selectors are evaluated for an element, not the other way around. The browser iterates the rules in the style sheets to see what rules applies to an element.